# In my second view controller, i can not add an @IBOutlet in the viewcontroller.swift???

Tags: xcode, swift, editor, assistant

I can right click and drag so it automatically adds an IBOutlet successfully but only in the first view controller. I can right click and drag but it will not add an iboutlet. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add @IBOutlet if the class you are trying to add it is a custom class of your controller.

In your case looks like firstViewController is the custom class of your view, what means that secondViewController cannot be.

[image]

In this example I can only add @IBOutlet to my LoginViewController, if I try to add in other classes XCode won't let me.